# Foursquare compact venues null after proguard

Tags: android, proguard, foursquare

Compact venues getting as null after proguard integration here is my configuration file. It's working fine without proguard.Actualy i am listing the places in a listview  now the list is generated but the values are blank

```
 -injars      bin/classes
-outjars     bin/classes-processed.jar
-libraryjars F:/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917/sdk/platforms/android-18/android.jar
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-dontshrink
-printmapping proguard\mapping.txt
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-keepattributes     *Annotation*,Signature,*Annotation*,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,InnerClasses
-renamesourcefileattribute demach
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-dontnote
-dontwarn
-ignorewarnings
-printconfiguration proguard\configuration.txt
-dump proguard\classes.txt
-printseeds proguard\seeds.txt

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity

-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference


-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider



#Google licensing files
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
    void set*(***);
    *** get*();
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
    public void *(android.view.View);
}

#Parcels and R
-keep class * extends android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.demach.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

# Support libraries on Android
-keep class android.support.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock {
    <init>(android.app.Activity, int);
}
# Http classes
-keep class org.apache.http.entity.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

# google GSON
-keep,allowshrinking class com.google.gson.stream.**

# VIEW - Setters and getters
-keep,allowshrinking class * extends android.view.View {
    <methods>;
}

# ACTIVITY
-keep,allowshrinking class * extends android.app.Activity {
    <methods>;
}

# PARCELABLE
-keep,allowshrinking class * extends android.os.Parcelable {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

# APPLICATION
-keep,allowshrinking class * extends android.app.Application {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

# SERVICE
-keep,allowshrinking class * extends android.app.Service {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

#Android classes
-keep,allowshrinking class * extends android.os.AsyncTask {
    <methods>;
}

#Android classes
-keep,allowshrinking class android.content.ContentProvider {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

#Android classes
-keep,allowshrinking class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

#Android classes
# R classes
-keep,allowshrinking class **.R$* {
    <fields>;
}


-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}


# Demach GSON files
-keep,allowshrinking class com.google.gson.demach.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

# Demach model
-keep,allowshrinking class com.demach.konotor.model.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

# Konotor MAIN class
-keep,allowshrinking class com.demach.konotor.Konotor {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

# Apache entity
-keep,allowshrinking class org.apache.http.entity.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

# Client models
-keep,allowshrinking class com.demach.konotor.client.model.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

# Service models
-keep,allowshrinking class com.demach.konotor.service.model.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

# Konotor cocos 2DX wrapper class
-keep,allowshrinking class com.demach.konotor.cocos2dx.KonotorCocos2DXWrapper {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

# Also keep - Enumerations. Keep the special static methods that are required in
# enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum  * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

# Keep names - Native method names. Keep all native class/method names.
-keepclasseswithmembers,allowshrinking class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last got the solution

```
-keepclassmembers public class fi.foyt.foursquare.api.entities.CompactVenue {
   <fields>;
   <methods>;
}
```